# ggplot2: legends for different aesthetics

Tags: r, ggplot2

I first plot histogram for a group of simulated data and fill the bars with one colour. Then I add the line of the density function from which the data was simulated from and make the line with a different colour. Now I want use legends to show one colour (the fill colour of the histogram) is for samples whereas the other (the colour of the line) is for theoretical density. How can I achieve this?

[image]

The code is as follows

```
require(ggplot2)
df <- data.frame(x=rnorm(10^4))
p <- ggplot(df, aes(x=x)) + geom_histogram(aes(y=..density..), fill='steelblue', colour='black', alpha=0.8, width=0.2)
x <- seq(-4, 4, 0.01)
df <- data.frame(x=x, y=dnorm(x))
p <- p + geom_line(data=df, aes(x=x, y=y), colour='red', size=1.5)
p
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Without changing your data at all, you can specify literal `aes()` values that you can define later via manual scales.

```
df <- data.frame(x=rnorm(10^4))
p <- ggplot(df, aes(x=x)) + geom_histogram(aes(y=..density.., fill="samples"), 
    alpha=0.8, colour="black", width=0.2)
p <- p+scale_fill_manual("",breaks="samples", values="steelblue")

x <- seq(-4, 4, 0.01)
df <- data.frame(x=x, y=dnorm(x))
p <- p + geom_line(data=df, aes(x=x, y=y, colour="theory"), size=1.5)
p <- p+scale_color_manual("",breaks="theory", values="red")
```

[image]

Answer (score 7):

You can do this by adding a new column to each of your data frames to create `fill` and `colour` aesthetics to go into the legend. In each case, there's only one category, but putting them inside the `aes()` gives you the legends you want:

```
require(ggplot2)

df <- data.frame(x=rnorm(10^4), fill=rep("Sample", 10^4))
p <- ggplot(df, aes(x=x)) + geom_histogram(aes(y=..density.., fill=fill), 
     colour='black', alpha=0.8, width=0.2) +
     scale_fill_manual(values="steelblue") + labs(fill="")

x <- seq(-4, 4, 0.01)
df <- data.frame(x=x, y=dnorm(x), colour=rep("Theoretical Density",length(x)))
p <- p + geom_line(data=df, aes(x=x, y=y, colour=line), size=1.5) +
         scale_colour_manual(values="red") + labs(colour="")
```

[image]